# Problem with import() statements which creating number of build files in Angular 8 build

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, build

Angular project using a file which contains a number of `import()` statements to load SVG files using `file-loader` web-pack plugin.

After the Angular 8 migration, I had a problem in which angular build, which creating a number of build files in `/dist` folder against each `import()` statement for es5 and es2015.

This is the file we exporting SVG to create a dynamic icon component, (Original file contains a number of imports)

eg:

[image]

This is the file creating against each `import()` statement in the above source file after build.

eg:

[image]

The above problem is leading to an increasing number of files and build CI is getting long-running.

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Could you tell you the previous version of angular of your project?

Comment: It was Angular ^7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved this problem by adding `/* webpackMode: "eager" */` in below snippet like:

```
/* webpackMode: "eager" */ '!file-loader?outputPath=assets
```

Please see the code snippet 1 in question

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your `tsconfig.json` file, add the `exclude` property and then give the file with the path that needs to be excluded during your build.

```
 "exclude": [
    "your_file_to_be_excluded"
  ]
```

**Note**: Do this with the `tsconfig.json` file located in the root level.

Comment: Its not working,
I added  
"exclude": [
    "./src/app/shared/components/icon/icon-set.exports.ts",
  ]

Comment: Try to remove the `./` before your link. There may be a problem with the location